# Error occurred during parsing: Fail to push limit. Google Ads Api

Tags: google-ads-api

Since we updated the Google Ads API from version 3 to 6 we get the error message "Fail to push the limit".

This happens if we try to link the Manager Account to the client.

```php
return (new GoogleAdsClientBuilder())
    ->fromFile()
    ->withOAuth2Credential($oAuth2Credential)
    ->withLoginCustomerId($loginCustomerId)
    ->build();
```

Is there any way to increase the limit?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue while working with firebase in PHP. I found that this error happens if the auto generated protobuf metadata files are modified. The files used to be tampered by FileZilla which I was using for uploading files to the server. This is what I did to get rid of it:

1. Zipped all my files
2. Uploaded through hosting provider's uploading utility
3. Removed files I had already uploaded through FileZilla
4. Extracted all the files in its desired place and tried to run it.
5. Boom! everything was fine. Error was gone.

Comment: I too had this same issue - never experienced this in my 25 years of IT, thank you for sharing the solution as it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error and even I recently upgraded and used composer to switch to newer version of Google Ads and forgot to remove the include statement that was used for earlier version, once removed, the error was gone. Remove the require/include statement from your code, hope that helps.

```
require __DIR__ . '/../google-ads-php/vendor/autoload.php';
```

OR

Your autogenerated protobuf files are being altered.
read more here: https://github.com/googleads/google-ads-php/issues/566

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip that might help somebody.

I faced this problem with some messages. The problem was that I was storing the messages in the database before sending them to rabbitMQ to be consumed later; however, in the end, we noticed that the database column type was not enough to store larger messages, and because of that, the message payload was cut off.

Looking at the payload encoded message, it looked okay, but when consuming it, I saw the `Fail to push limit` exception from Protobuf.

---

Try to double-check if your encoded message that is being produced is not being cut for any reason. Depending on how you produce the messages, you might not see the error on the producer, but just on the consumer side as "Fail to push limit".